Having intrusive thoughts
I have a question if i ignore my waswas intrusive thoughts completely will I be sinful? And by ignoring I mean letting it pass and if I don’t avoid them or try to stop them. And they really are bad thoughts that I’m in too much pain because of it, everytime my heart gets so heavy to the point breathing becomes really hard for me.

Alhamdulillah,
No, you will not be sinful if you ignore the waswas (intrusive thoughts) and let them pass without acting upon them or entertaining them.
In Islam, we are not held accountable for the thoughts that cross our minds involuntarily, as long as we do not dwell on them or act upon them intentionally.
The Prophet Muhammad ﷺ said:

"Allah has forgiven my nation for the thoughts that occur to their minds, as long as they do not act upon them or speak about them."

Intrusive thoughts, especially those of a disturbing or blasphemous nature, are often a trial and whisperings from Shaytan meant to cause distress. The best way to deal with them is to:

Ignore them and do not entertain them or analyze their content.
Turn your heart and mind towards Allah immediately by remembering Him, reciting adhkar, or engaging in acts of worship.
Do not feel guilty or troubled, as you are not accountable for thoughts you did not willingly entertain.

It is also important not to avoid or try to stop the thoughts forcefully, as this can paradoxically make them more persistent. Just let them pass like clouds without paying attention to them.
I understand these intrusive thoughts can be very distressing and burdensome. Be patient, have faith in Allah's mercy, and keep your heart and tongue firm in your faith. With time and training of the mind, they will subside, insha'Allah.
Do not hesitate to seek professional counseling as well, if the thoughts become overly overwhelming. May Allah ease your affairs and grant you relief from this burden.
And Allah knows best!

lots of people will say to you only say

auzubillah minashaitan nirajeem

Yes, true that it need to be said. But when you have a situation point breathing becomes really hard for you and you know it's sinful but can't stop it. It means you need to talk to a authentic Raki. You might be effected by hasad, or black magic.
